# How to conduct multivariate regression in Excel?

Tags: excel

I've been searching the web for possibilities to conduct multivariate regressions in Excel, where I've seen that Analysis ToolPak can make the job done.

However it seems that Analysis ToolPak can handle multi*variable* linear regression but **not** multi*variate* linear regression (where the latter is that one may have more than one dependent variable Y1,...,Yn = x1+x2..+xn and the former that a dependent variable can have multiple independent variables Y = x1+x2+..+xn).

Is there a way to conduct *multivariate* regressions in Excel or should I start looking for other programs like R?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-multivariate-regression-excel-42353.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's actually the tutorial I used. However, using two Y variables got me the error that the dependent variables must be written in the same row or column. For my problem though, this raises an issue as I only have 1 independent variable and 2 dependent variables, and it is the "Connection"  between these I need to find.

Comment: sorry past my skills... Hope someone else can take it further.

Comment: Multivariate linear regression is one dependent variable (usually denoted Y) and n>1 than independent variables (denoted X1, X2, ..., Xn). The case with of one independent variable is simple linear regression. In both cases there is usually a constant term. In simple case, process estimates a and b for equation Y = a+bX given m>2 observation pairs (Y,X). In multiple case, process estimates a, b1, b2, ..., bn for eqn Y = a+b1X1+b2X2+...+ bnXn, given m>n+1 observation tuples (Y,X1,X2,...,Xn). Linear Regression in Analysis ToolPak handles both types with ease - that is its purpose.